# Fast generation of partial DataFrames with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file like this. This file have about 2 million rows.

```
2020/03/05 14:59:12.093,92.7884,93.8238
2020/03/05 14:59:14.571,97.1114,51.3926
2020/03/05 14:59:16.035,56.1351,62.6697
2020/03/05 14:59:16.992,90.3412,64.8728
         :
```

I would like to create pandas dataframes so that each dataframe has 2 minutes span and sliding 20 seconds as follows.

`DataFrame1:`

```
2020/03/05 14:59:12.093,92.7884,93.8238
2020/03/05 14:59:14.571,97.1114,51.3926
2020/03/05 14:59:16.035,56.1351,62.6697
           :
2020/03/05 15:01:11.652,90.6966,37.9923
2020/03/05 15:01:11.918,35.8304,1.04157
```

`DataFrame2:`

```
2020/03/05 14:59:33.086,85.2834,57.327
2020/03/05 14:59:34.373,94.0521,33.8809
2020/03/05 14:59:38.752,36.8084,37.9878
           :
2020/03/05 15:01:33.090,70.4679,54.3437
```

and so on.

I know I can do this with the following code.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, names=['time', 'colA', 'colB'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format=r'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df = df.set_index('time')
extracted_dfs = []
startdatetime = df.index[0]
enddatetime = df.index[len(df)-1]
curdatetime = startdatetime
while curdatetime < enddatetime:
    extracted_df = df[curdatetime:curdatetime + pd.Timedelta(seconds=120)].copy()
    extracted_dfs.append(extracted_df)
    curdatetime = curdatetime + pd.Timedelta(seconds=20)
```

But this code is very slow. It takes about 30 seconds.
How can I do this faster?

Comment: I found something interesting, not sure how effective, but worth a look. [pandas.DataFrame.between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html)

Comment: Do you need real copies of all the data, or would views be sufficient?  Making a copy of each 120 second window every 20 seconds means you're creating 6 copies of every row, which of course is slow and wasteful of resources.  Is that necessary for some other reason, such as that you are going to modify the same row in different ways in each DataFrame?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yes, I need real copies. I'm going to modify the value of every row to the difference of the first row.

Comment: A couple of questions: (1) have you considered parallelizing this, using Dask for example?
(2) going back to the copy vs. view question, what about creating a single larger dataframe that contains duplications of these rows? What that Suffice?

Comment: Have you tried [Dask](https://dask.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to under 6 seconds on my 2.67GHz laptop.
Used 2M rows within 24 hours and got 4,320 extracted dfs, I'm guessing is a good enough scaled test.

It seems we save a lot of time by taking `curdatetime + pd.Timedelta()` out of the loop.

```
### toy dataframe
start = pd.to_datetime('2020-03-05 14:00')
n = int(2e6)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': np.random.choice(100, n), 'B': np.random.choice(100, n)},
    index=start + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.rand(n)*86400, unit='seconds')
    ).sort_index()

t0 = time()

### build all start datetimes for windows
gtimes = np.arange(start=df.index[0], stop=df.index[-1],
    step=pd.Timedelta(20, unit='seconds'))
extracted_dfs = [df.loc[gt:lt] for gt, lt in
    zip(gtimes, gtimes + pd.Timedelta(120, unit='seconds'))]


print(f'runtime: {time() - t0}s')
print(*extracted_dfs[:2], sep='\n\n')
```

Output

```
runtime: 5.9694719314575195s
                                A   B
2020-03-05 14:00:00.029956126  38  47
2020-03-05 14:00:00.043794997  19  93
2020-03-05 14:00:00.274295160  24  26
2020-03-05 14:00:00.345806566   7  96
2020-03-05 14:00:00.358988998  83  18
...                            ..  ..
2020-03-05 14:01:59.811072868  45  75
2020-03-05 14:01:59.895038311  36  26
2020-03-05 14:01:59.936082342  78   6
2020-03-05 14:01:59.974735739  17  25
2020-03-05 14:01:59.985301083   1  34

[2802 rows x 2 columns]

                                A   B
2020-03-05 14:00:20.037424719  95  49
2020-03-05 14:00:20.071532168  70  37
2020-03-05 14:00:20.086438199  46  45
2020-03-05 14:00:20.197759064  60  61
2020-03-05 14:00:20.261713915  31  20
...                            ..  ..
2020-03-05 14:02:19.633312110  30  34
2020-03-05 14:02:19.646400725  50   2
2020-03-05 14:02:19.804335407  40  75
2020-03-05 14:02:19.841056690  18  75
2020-03-05 14:02:19.857622011  90  46

[2768 rows x 2 columns]
```